# I want to do a win10 exe software, the function is when switch Between Chinese and English, pop-up notification

Tags: c++, windows

1.I use the Microsoft Input Method.
2.I want to make it by C++.

I need help with:
1.Detect the switch between Chinese and English in the user input method;
2.Prompt notifications. But I can't do both of them.

expect: when switch Between Chinese and English, pop-up notification

Comment: such as: https://www.codenong.com/cs107125038/

Comment: [WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-inputlangchange)